# PHP/SQL group/compare

Tags: php, sql

How do one compare string X to string X in a previous result set and apply something if something is part of a group but only if it lack the same value as another value.

What i need is basically to identify where `city` and `linkcity` is the same but only IF linkcity actually have more results then 1. The problem is that ie NYC == NYC works fine but some of these airports have the same `linkcity` as name without there being more results/airports for the given `linkcity`.

Therefor i can't simply do a `if($city == $linkcity) { /* do stuff*/ }`.

So how do i compare or group this so i can correctly identify the results that has `linkcity` that isn't unique so that i can manipulate that single result?

-

## **SQL Table example**

Example output from code "PHP/SQL" further below.

```
city, name, linkcity, name, name
----------------------------------------------    
EWR, Newark, NYC, North America, USA
JFK, John F. Kennedy, NYC, North America, USA
NYC, New York, NYC, North America, USA
BNY, Bellona, BNY, South Pacific, Salomon Islands
LNY, Lanai City (Hawaii), LNY, North America, USA
NYO, Nyköping/Skavsta, NYO, Europe, Sweden
```

-

## **PHP/SQL**

```
$db = "xxx";
$user = "yyy";
$pass = "zzz";
$cursor_type = 1;
$conn = odbc_connect($db, $user, $pass, $cursor_type);
if(!$conn) { exit("Connection Failed:<br>" . $conn); }

$sql = "
    SELECT
    a.id,
    a.city,
    a.name,
    a.linkcity,
    b.name,
    c.name
    FROM dbo.city a

    JOIN dbo.citycontinent b
    ON b.id = a.continent

    JOIN dbo.citycountry c
    ON c.id = a.country
";

$rs = odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
if(!$rs) { exit("Error in SQL"); }

    while(odbc_fetch_row($rs)) {

        $city = odbc_result($rs, 'city');
        $linkCity = odbc_result($rs, 'linkcity');
        $name = utf8_encode(odbc_result($rs, 'name'));
        $continent = utf8_encode(odbc_result($rs, 5));
        $country = utf8_encode(odbc_result($rs, 6));

                echo '<tr>';
        echo "<td>$city</td>";
        echo "<td>$name</td>";
        echo "<td>$linkCity</td>";
        echo "<td>$continent</td>";
        echo "<td>$country</td>";
        echo '</tr>';

    } //end WHILE loop
```

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Are you trying to find where `linkcity` matches multiple cites?

Comment: Yeah, that would be the result of what i'm trying to do and IF that's the case do something with the one (in that group) where `$city == $linkcity`.